# python gtk3 popup window activate

Tags: python-3.x, popup, gtk3

Environment Python 3, Gtk3:
I want to have an entry in a Gtk3 form that displays a date in DD/MM form. I intend to use a popup window that will display a calendar and return the day and month selected. I assume that a click on the (blank) entry will create a signal to start that process, but can someone tell me what GtkEntry signal I should be?
Thanks 
Graeme

Comment: Take a look at the `focus in` signal. The docs are [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-focus-in-event).

Comment: Thanks. I realised shortly after posting that it would have something to do with "focus". I'll count to 100 before pressing "submit" next time !